# How to append method results to two list in one call in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a method return two variables, I'd like to append those two return results to two lists. If I use temp variable, that's doable, is there any better way? In just one call?

eg:

```
def myfunc() :
    return "myname", "mypos"


name_list = []
pos_list = []

# may I merge the following three lines in one call?
name, pos = myfunc()
name_list.append(name)
pos_list.append(pos)
```

Comment: If you want those lists separate like that, then that’s your best choice for appending those values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your solution is perfectly fine.**

As stated in [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), *“simple is better than complex”* and *“readability counts”*, so focus on that instead of trying to reach an arbitrary and meaningless goal of “fewest lines” or “fewest variables used”. Neither of those matter at all.

Sure, you can somehow put this into a single line. Chances are, it will become very gimmicky and while you may understand it today, and maybe even tomorrow, next month it will give you a hard time.

Also, a common way to do this is to abuse list comprehensions. List comprehensions are used to *create* lists in which you collect things. Using them just for side effects is a common antipattern that you should avoid because you are creating a meaningless list just for the sake of putting more into a single line (again hurting readability).

---

So, your solution is good. With your premise, I’d say it’s the perfect solution to put those two values into those two separate lists:

```
name, pos = myfunc()
name_list.append(name)
pos_list.append(pos)
```

You can easily understand what’s going on. Furthermore, your temporary variables have a useful name that makes it easy to understand what those multiple return values from that function are.

What alternatives would there be if you didn’t have the requirement of this list format? Well, it depends a lot on your use case, but you could also collect the result in the same list, as the same tuple your function returns. Maybe even return a named tuple from your function so you have the semantic information what value is what. Or return a custom object, or store it in a dictionary if you are just mapping names to positions…

But functions returning multiple things at the same time are usually not that easily understood on their own. So it’s fine if the calling code gets a bit more expressive to then work with the result. That way, it becomes easy to understand, even in a year.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is this:

```
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]
data = myfunc()
for x, ls in zip(data, lists):
    ls.append(x)
```

However, doing this only really makes sense if your function returns a very large tuple meant for a large number of lists. If you only have two like in your example, you're better off sticking with your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to do this in one line, but this accomplishes the task:
`list(map(lambda x: x[0].append(x[1]), zip([name_list, pos_list], my_func())))`

Note that this statement doesn't return anything useful, it just modifies your lists for you.

Comment: My answer is basically the same approach as stybl's but I tried to cram it into a single line. I'd say his answer is more pythonic than mine.

Comment: Still have to give you props for being able to cram all of that in there

Comment: Props for being able to write such gimmicky code, sure, but at the same time, I don’t believe you should seriously suggest this as a way to do this.

Comment: @poke yeah, I wasn't sure what the OP meant by "in one call". My interpretation was that they were asking for a single line of code doing that. I totally agree with you that this is horrible style which is why I've upvoted stybl's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A longer way to achieve this that could be useful if the `function` returned more values could be to use a `list comprehension` with `enumerate`:

```
[lst.append(myfunc()[i]) for i, lst in enumerate([name_list, pos_list])]
```

this takes advantage of the facts that `python` `lists` are [`mutable`](http://bjc.berkeley.edu/bjc-r/cur/programming/python/list_mutability.html).